# RHEL 7 / Centos 7 Copy package with all depedencies from server A (installed package) to server B (offline)

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, yum, operating-system

I have two server,then these servers need to install `postgresql10` , **server A** could install `postgresql10` using `yum install` , but **server B** has a rule that is not allowed to connect the internet.
So I trying to install with `rpm` file in **server B**.

1. I download `postgresql10` with all **depedencies** using `yumdownloader` from my development server
2. I upload all `rpm` files into **server B**
3. I start to install with command `rpm -ivh *.rpm` inside **server B**
4. After I try that so many `depedenciess` are not downloaded by `yumdownloader`

My idea is **make a file that contain the package and all depedencies in single file, like `tar.gz` file then I install to other server as simple as extract file** but I still research, then still stuck on it.

So if you has a story same as me, what best way did you have?
Is there any `script` that could help my problem.
**Please share with me, Thank you very much**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way, but it is quite tricky and might mess up your servers, so be **very careful**.

Nomenclature:

- **online** : your system that is connected to the repositories
- **offline**: your system that is not connected

Steps:

Compress your rpm database from the **offline** system and transfer it to the **online** system:

```
cd /var/lib/rpm/
tar -cvzf /tmp/rpmdb.tgz *
scp /tmp/rpmdb.tgz root@online:/tmp
```

on your **online** system; replace your rpm db with the one from the **offline** system:

```
cp -r /var/lib/rpm{,.bak} # back up your rpmdb from your online system. Make sure not to lose this!!
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/*
cd /var/lib/rpm
tar -xvf /tmp/rpmdb.tgz # now your online system pretends to have the rpm database from the offline system. Don't start really installing / uninstalling rpms or you'll break everything
```

now simulate your update with download-only:

```
yum install --downloadonly # or
zypper up --download-only
```

Now you can fetch all the downloaded packages and they should suffice for updating your offline system

And now restore your **online** machine:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm
cp -r /var/lib/rpm{.bak,}
```

Comment: After this, we can use `yum install $package --downloadonly` or `yumdownloader --resolve $package` , then move depedencies into server without internet connection